# Get a record from List with the max date

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have several records in List of actionHistorys and out of them I am trying to get hold of only one record of type MyactionHistory that has the max createdate field. CreateDateTime is a datetimeTime field.

I tried to go some look up and search but couldn't find a solution

```
List<MyActionHistory> actionHistorys = oFD.GetMyActionHistoryList();  // This should have about 4 objects or records
// This is where I am confused..Not working 
MyActionHistory MaxRecord= actionHistorys.Find(p => actionHistorys.Exists(o => o.CreateDateTime ))
```

Comment: How about ordering by date descending and taking first record? `actionHistorys.OrderByDescending(h => h.CreateDateTime).First()`

Comment: yes trying that now.. Problem is I had not included using System.Linq; in my project, so I was not getting those options.

Comment: @timur, yeah you are correct, I deleted my answer as well as comment

Comment: I'm surprised that MaxBy hasn't been added as a standard LINQ method yet.  It exists in Reactive Extensions.  Anyway, you can use MoreLINQ https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#maxby to solve your problem.

Comment: @timur yes that worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @timur. Following piece of code worked

```
actionHistorys.OrderByDescending(h => h.CreateDateTime).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [MoreLINQ MaxBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#maxby)

usings

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MoreLinq;
```

code

```
MyActionHistory maxRecord = actionHistorys
    .MaxBy(o => o.CreateDateTime)
    .Take(1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is more efficient than sorting the whole list descending and then taking the first item.  If I understand the implementation of MaxBy and Take correctly this will make a single pass through the list and return the one with the highest value (first with the highest value if multiple have same highest value).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyActionHistory MaxRecord = actionHistorys.OrderBy((x) => x.CreateDateTime).LastOrDefault();
```

Or:

```
MyActionHistory MaxRecord = actionHistorys.OrderByDescending((x) => x.CreateDateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```